# Laravel validating form request using repository setup

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.1 and would like some advice on validating a form request using a repository setup as opposed to the standard way of validating using requests.  Here is my setup below:

My Route:

```
Route::post('/users/administrators/{user}/edit', 'AdministratorController@update');
```

My Controller (AdministratorController):

```
/**
 * Create a new instance.
 *
 * @return Collection
 */
public function __construct(UserRepoInterface $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id)
{
    $this->user->updateUser($id);

    return Redirect::back()->withMessage('Your changes have been saved.');
}
```

My Model (User):

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function showableFields()
    {
        return ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'created_at'];
    }

    public function headers()
    {
        return ['Date'];
    }
}
```

My Interface (UserRepoServiceProvider):

```
<?php 

namespace App\Repos\User;

interface UserRepoInterface {

    /**
      * Update user.
      *
     * @param $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function updateUser($user);
}
```

My Interface methods (EloquentUser):

```
<?php 

namespace App\Repos\User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\UsersRoles;

class EloquentUser implements UserRepoInterface
{
    protected $user, $roles;

    /**
     * Create a new EloquentUser repository instance.
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, UsersRoles $roles)
    {

        $this->user     = $user;
        $this->roles    = $roles;
    }

    /**
     * Update user.
     *
     * @param $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function updateUser($user)
    {

    }

}
```

I am specifying the service provider in /config/app.php:

```
App\Providers\UserRepoServiceProvider::class
```

I am booting up the provider using the below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Repos\User\EloquentUser;

class UserRepoServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Repos\User\UserRepoInterface', function($app) 
        {
            return new EloquentUser(
                new \App\Models\User,
                new \App\Models\UsersRoles
            );
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

What is the most efficient and dynamic way for me to validate form requests coming in?  Is it to use request validation as normal or can this process be made dynamic somehow?

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Any MF still not yet answered